# How to hide a Tab Bar in Maya docked window?

Tags: python, maya

[image]

I want to hide the tab bar when docking a window made of Maya workspacecontrol.

What I want is to be able to select and move to a dotted line like Maya's shelf window.

[image]

I am testing with the code below.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def createCustomWorkspaceControlUI(*args):
  cmds.columnLayout()
  cmds.button()
  cmds.button()
  cmds.button()

cmds.workspaceControl("myCustomWorkspaceControl", retain=False, floating=True, uiScript="createCustomWorkspaceControlUI()");
```